# Extract Tensorboard Histogram data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Following [the tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensorboard_histograms), I got a histogram by Tensorflow,

```py
import tensorflow as tf

k = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# Make a normal distribution, with a shifting mean
mean_moving_normal = tf.random_normal(shape=[1000], mean=(5*k), stddev=1)
# Record that distribution into a histogram summary
tf.summary.histogram("normal/moving_mean", mean_moving_normal)

# Setup a session and summary writer
sess = tf.Session()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/histogram_example")

summaries = tf.summary.merge_all()

# Setup a loop and write the summaries to disk
N = 400
for step in range(N):
  k_val = step/float(N)
  summ = sess.run(summaries, feed_dict={k: k_val})
  writer.add_summary(summ, global_step=step)
```

Next step, I want to extract the histogram data using API of Tensorboard, my code is here

```py
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_accumulator import EventAccumulator
event_acc = EventAccumulator(summary_path)
event_acc.Reload()
# Show all tags in the log file
tags = event_acc.Tags()
hist_dict = {}
for hist_event in event_acc.Histograms('normal/moving_mean'):
    hist_dict.update({hist_event.step: (hist_event.histogram_value.bucket_limit,
                                        hist_event.histogram_value.bucket)})
```

However, it only returned the last output. How can get all the data?

Answer (score -1):

When passing a "size_guidance" to the `EventAccumulator` constructor, you are good to go. Something like:

```
event_acc = EventAccumulator(path, size_guidance={
        'histograms': REAL_STEP_COUNT,
})
```

Comment: Found a solution. Forget my original post.

Comment: i edited this post. Before i pointed out that the CompressedHistogram function returns all steps. Someone thought this hint was bad enough to vote it down. What you can see here is actually working.

Comment: Each step the shape if 1000, but I got only 139. Can you give a detailed working solution?